# How to add social login options in website?

Tags: php, login-script, social-networking

I am using php/mysql for my website. I have created my own login/registration system, but I want to also integrate three social login options, Google, Facebook and Twitter in my website. Using them user will be able to login and able to post stuff in website.

Just like Stackoverflow did for its login/registration form.

I want to know the libraries and code which I reuiqre for the social login implementation. Is there any open-source library using which I can integrate all three, or I need to setup each separately.

Please provide links, tutorials and code to integrate social logins in my php webiste.

Thanks!

Comment: Each of them has a different auth scheme - they're not too hard to implement, but I haven't heard of a library to abstract this yet. Let's see if someone else has...

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow implements [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). Check out [Plaxo OpenID recipe](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe). Nice one on how to go about implementing openid.

Comment: I am not a big fan of OpenId, I only like to integrate Google, Facebook and Twitter, because they are the leaders and non-techies users also have accounts on these websites.

Answer (score 1):

you should check out [google friend connect](http://code.google.com/apis/friendconnect/docs/registration.html) or [rpxnow](https://rpxnow.com/)(not free when site gets a lot of traffic) which give you simple integration for all these providers at once.

Comment: I guess if your project is worth a little investment, rpxnow would be near optimal for you.

Comment: yeah or google friend connect is also very good. Also very easy to implement in my opinion.